# Перебор 10+ массивов JS HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Задача написать HTML и залить на сотовый для поездки в Крым, пока, по приезду нет интернета. Накидал 40 маршрутов с достопримечательностями как добраться от/до автовокзала Севастополя, да и много всего, два поля, откуда и куда, но видимо не расчитал я свои познания 15-и летней давности и нагородил. Помогите справиться!

Всем бонус как прогуляться по Крыму карта на Тындексе: https://yandex.ru/maps/?um=constructor%3A95b361d5f0d9e1b55b8ea7c7ee060dfc55b4cfe75d27ec61919e6e7195858bc5&source=constructorLink (Если Модераторы и Админы позволят)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <title>untitled</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="generator" content="Geany 1.27" />
</head>

<body>
    <!--form name="trans" onsubmit=""-->
        <input type="text" id="fromthein" value="Посёлок Кальфа"> From: <span id="fromtheout"></span><br>
        <input type="text" id="tothein"> To: <span id="totheout"></span><br>
        <span id="transport"></span>
        <!--input type="submit"-->
    <!--/form-->
    <script>
    //Откуда и куда
        var fromtheinelement = document.body.children[0]; //Поле откуда
        var totheinelement = document.body.children[3]; //Поле куда

        fromtheinelement.oninput = function() {
            document.getElementById('fromtheout').innerHTML = fromtheinelement.value;
            //Поиск по маршруту 

            for (var j = 0; j < arr_t.length; j++) {

                var tstring = 'arr_' + arr_t[j];

                for (var i = 0; i < tstring.lenght; i++) {

                    if (fromtheinelement.value == 'tstring' + [i]) 
                        {
                                alert( tstring );
                                document.getElementById('fromtheout').innerHTML = fromtheinelement.value + ' Совпало ' + tstring[0];
                                document.getElementById('transport').innerHTML += ' ' + tstring[0];
                        }{
                                alert( tstring + ' нет такого значения');
                    }

            }

            //для добавления маршрута
            //document.getElementById('transport').innerHTML = arr_a2[0];

            }   
            //document.getElementById('transport').innerHTML += ' ' + arr_a2[0];
        };

    //Проверка туда ли мы едем?


    //Переменные, траспорт и остановки, создание массива
        var a2 = 'Aвтобус 2, Стрелецкая бухта, Посёлок Кальфа, Песочная бухта, парк Анны Ахматовой, Херсонес Таврический, ЦУМ, Площадь Ушакова, панорама, бастион, театр, библиотека, гостиница Украина, 5-й километр Балаклавского шоссе';
        var a9 = 'Aвтобус 9, 2-е отделение, 5-й километр Балаклавского шоссе, Балаклава';
        var t12 ='Троллейбус 12, 5-й километр Балаклавского шоссе (кольцевой), Площадь Ушакова, панорама, бастион, театр, библиотека, гостиница Украина, Площадь Нахимова, Графская пристань, Морской вокзал, Памятник затопленным кораблям, Набережная, Дельфинарий, Артиллерийская бухта, Площадь Лазарева, Центральный рынок, Комсомольский парк';

    //заводим массив на транспорт
        var trans = 'a2,a9,t12,a14,m14,m17,t17,a17,m20,t20,a22ar,a133a,m400,a3,a34a,m128,t1,t3,t4,m4,t7,t9,t22,m25,m26,m71,a107,m107,a109,m109,m110,m112,a133a,m195,a48,a51,a52,a52a';  

        var arr_t = trans.split(',');

        for (var t = 0; t < arr_t.length; t++) {
        }

    //формируем массив остановок        
        var arr_a2 = a2.split(', ');

        for (var i = 0; i < arr_a2.length; i++) {
            //alert( 'Остановки: ' + arr_a2[i] );
        }

        var arr_a9 = a9.split(', ');

        for (var i = 0; i < arr_a9.length; i++) {
            //alert( 'Остановки: ' + arr_a9[i] );
        }

        var arr_t12 = t12.split(', ');

        for (var i = 0; i < arr_t12.length; i++) {
            //alert( 'Остановки: ' + arr_t12[i] );
        }


    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: В чём проблема? Не проще было воспользоваться специализированными сервисами? Например, [прогрузить карту](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6291838?hl=ru&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid)...

Comment: @Jagailo я только за, но тогда знаешь только названия и непонимаешь где это на карте, мне будет удобнее так. А карты Google в Крыму работают из рук вон плохо. Составляю себе шпаргалку.

Comment: https://yandex.ru/support/navigator/concept/offline.html

Answer (score 1):

Варианты

- купить нормальную бумажную карту + туристичекий справочник
- использовать оffline карты на смартфоне
- распечатать нужные маршруты
- создать pdf

Был в Крыму, и не раз, не понимаю вот это - **"..пока, по приезду нет интернета.."**.

Не думаю, что "приложение html, сделанное на коленке" будет лучше нормальных карт. Плюс потраченное впустую время. Если все же хочется, то можно использовать [Lodash](https://lodash.com/), это поможет в работе с массивами. Только не забыть его подключить (залить вместе с html).